# Как правильно отправить credentials типа "SSH Username with private key" в Jenkins через API?

Tags: api, jenkins

Вопрос касается создания credentials типа **"SSH Username with private key"**.
Принцип создания простой (часть bash-скрипта):

```
...
tee credentials.xml >/dev/null <<EOF
<com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey>
  <scope>GLOBAL</scope>
  <id>$ID</id>
  <username>$Username</username>
  <privateKeySource class="com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey\$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource">
    <privateKey>$(cat $PrivateSSHKeyFile)</privateKey>
  </privateKeySource>
  <usernameSecret>false</usernameSecret>
</com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey>
EOF

Crumb=$(curl --insecure -sS --user $Login:$Token "$ServerURI/crumbIssuer/api/json" | cut -d"\"" -f8)
curl --insecure -X POST -sS "$ServerURL/credentials/store/folder/domain/_/createCredentials" \
  --user $Login:$Token \
  --header "Jenkins-Crumb:$Crumb" \
  --header "content-type:application/xml" \
  --data @credentials.xml

rm credentials.xml
```

Когда в Jenkins пытаюсь "воспользоваться" созданным credentials, получаю ошибку `Permission denied, please try again.`. То есть очевидно, что текст ключа искажается при передаче.

Вышеописанным способом создал credentials типа "Secret text" и "Username with password" и они успешно работают.
Мне кажется, что всё дело в том, как в xml передаётся сам ssh-ключ, то есть дело в строке `<privateKey>$(cat $PrivateSSHKeyFile)</privateKey>`.
В чём конкретно может быть проблема?

P.S.: пытался "руками" сформировать файл `credentials.xml` - не помогает.
На всякий случай привожу содержимое `credentials.xml`:

```
<com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey>
  <scope>GLOBAL</scope>
  <id>server</id>
  <username>username</username>
  <privateKeySource class="com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource">
    <privateKey>-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
ZC/TIwEve23ULkHdN/IRfya1ikcF7BTucyq58awbNjF3dJUnhrJlUxTK+AfNDrUW
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAmIU+giZXwRgKALYRFFoWMzTrZTLCfoz6WIBlQvzq7pm6SVkQ
...
hKhdNl3IHAcT4GPGR2BJBsuaqry8RsXaqf134dMCgYBtSWbmk4BV23iLwpxteThi
kwdFa3mVOrXaUQrnNLEVU8xnScjHNNISy2xfWv0joG/VZRbpD9Q=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----</privateKey>
  </privateKeySource>
  <usernameSecret>false</usernameSecret>
</com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в символах перевода строк в ключе. Вместо них должны быть символы `&#xa;` и ключ должен состоять из одной строки.
Доработанный итоговый скрипт будет выглядеть так:

```
PrivateSSHKeyFile=$(sed 's/$/\&#xa;/' key_file | tr -d '\n')

tee credentials.xml >/dev/null <<EOF
<com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey>
  <scope>GLOBAL</scope>
  <id>$ID</id>
  <username>$Username</username>
  <privateKeySource class="com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey\$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource">
    <privateKey>$(echo ${PrivateSSHKeyFile::-5})</privateKey>
  </privateKeySource>
  <usernameSecret>false</usernameSecret>
</com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey>
EOF

Crumb=$(curl --insecure -sS --user $Login:$Token "$ServerURI/crumbIssuer/api/json" | cut -d"\"" -f8)
curl --insecure -X POST -sS "$ServerURL/credentials/store/folder/domain/_/createCredentials" \
  --user $Login:$Token \
  --header "Jenkins-Crumb:$Crumb" \
  --header "content-type:application/xml" \
  --data @credentials.xml

rm credentials.xml
```